# Changing language of functions in Excel 2011 for Mac

Tags: macos, language, microsoft-excel-2011

I use Office 2011 for mac, with Norwegian language. I don't mind menus and such being Norwegian, but for some reason, the names of functions have been translated from English to Norwegian, and that is a royal pain. It's quite cumbersome to search for a solution to some problem online, and then have to look up or figure out what the Norwegian equivalent of the function names are.

Is it possible to change the language of the functions to another language (English)?

Comment: Does it change if you change the MSO Language Settings, within office rather than system wide?

Comment: Thank you for your input. Sadly, this only appears to affect the spell checker.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if you're still using Office 2011, but in Office 365 you can do this via Terminal:

$ defaults write com.microsoft.Excel AppleLanguages '("en-US")'

Then restart Excel. Note that this also changes the UI to English, haven't found a way to change only function names.